# Registry Keys error when installing SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express on a Windows XP machine that already has SQL Server Management Studio 2005 installed on it. I would like to have both of these instances installed at the same time.

During the installation, all of the Setup Support Rules passed except for

```
"Consistency validation for SQL Server registry keys"
```

with the error

```
"The SQL Server registry keys from a prior installation cannot be modified. To continue, see SQL Server Setup documentation about how to fix registry keys."
```

All of the resources and suggested fixes I have checked so far have been unhelpful in that they haven't really dealt with my specific scenario with this error, and I don't want to modify any registry keys unless I am sure of the fix I am making. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i eventually found the answer to my own problem in this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/fdb33ba1-a67a-4cd7-bccb-90ac07a43e1c

```
Steps

    1. Located HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server in registry
    2. Right click and go to Permission
    3. Click on Advance
    4. Tick on both check box (I. Inherit from parent the permission... II. Replace permission entries on all child objects...), click OK
    5. Click OK again
```

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this post because for some reason, nobody seems to have written this particular situation. That's a bit surprised because it involves an extensively used 3rd party software package.

My problem was caused by another non-standard instance of SQL that was installed as part of my ACT! contact mgmt system. It took about 3 days of reading and trial-error to figure it out.

Need to open Control Panel, Admionstrator Tool, Services. Then go through and STOP EVERY SERVICE that refers to SQL. My first one, MSSQL$ACT7, seemed to stop all of them since there were never any other SQL services running on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what registry keys are being accessed, and what access is failing